# What are some best practices for managing data in a cloud?

Tags: cloud

I was wondering the various ways of storing and retrieving data in a cloud?

How does Facebook do it?  Apple (i.e. mobileme)? google app engine, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first thing you'll notice is that data is typically stored in key-value pairs rather than relationally. This is done for speed and to enable the cloud OS to better distribute data over multiple nodes.

Comment: I came across a google video with a talk by one of the top salesforce.com guys, and they seemed to be have not a lot of tables in their schema, and one of their tables seemed "skinny"/EAV like, as you described above

Answer (score 2):

Slide 8 in this presentation is "Facebook's Data Infrastructure":

http://www.slideshare.net/guest5b1607/text-analytics-summit-2009-roddy-lindsay-social-media-happiness-petabytes-and-lols

It's interesting to see how it has evolved.